# Play audio over network with Windows 7?

Tags: audio, networking, .net-framework, streaming

I have a unique situation where I'd like to stream audio (ALL audio, not just mp3s, etc) from my laptop to another computer over the network.  I live in a studio apartment and my laptop is my main computer but I'd like it's audio to play on my htpc with a nice stereo system.  Since it's a studio, both computers are in the same room so I don't want 2 sets of speakers.  I want my computer to directly play back through the stereo.

I used to do this with pulseaudio but my job now requires that I run Windows full time.  I'm aware of Shoutcast and other similar streaming solutions but I don't want any transcoding done.  It's a waste of CPU and not to mention my laptop fans, and I don't mind the network bandwidth that uncompressed audio requires.  Is there a way to run Shoutcast without encoding?

Also, I know that Windows Remote Desktop can play audio over the network pretty easily.  Is this part of .Net that I could just code a simple app that streams the audio without RD'ing in?

I also don't want to run it over a physical wire. :)