# Output laptop's audio wirelessly to desktop?

Tags: wireless-networking, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play audio over network with Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/41236/play-audio-over-network-with-windows-7)

Okay assuming I have a desktop and a laptop, they are both on the same network. I've already use [synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to control the two computer seenlessly. The only problem that I have is the laptop's speaker kinda sucks pretty bad.

Is there any way to "*add a network speaker*" and stream all the audio to my desktop's speaker and play it there ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question to yours on SU already [here](https://superuser.com/questions/41236/play-audio-over-network-with-windows-7/95026). If the answers there don't help you, I have a couple suggestions.

A program called [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/) seems to do exactly what you need but you have to pay for it.

You could use RDC (Remote Desktop) to share sound. It would be kind of inefficient though considering RDC was not created with sound sharing as it's main feature.

Comment: cool thanks for pointing this out didn't realize this before